# Should I be creating a Region for each beacon (android beacon library)

Tags: ibeacon-android, eddystone

I've got a few beacons... and would like to be able to handle those beacons a bid different. I've managed to create a Region that captures **any** beacon for testing purposes, and it does trigger using my eddystone beacon... because the region never specified id1/id2, naturally didEnterRegion provides no detail

Ideal scenario would be my app listens for all beacons, if they match a prefix great, quick hit to server for extra information... and act if necessary.

I've tried calling startRangingNotifications on beaconManager after being notified a region was entered, however I suspect because its implemented in application class (that implements bootstrapnotifier) its not connecting to service.

I dont REALLY care about distance or any other telemetry (although it would be nice), just want to know id of a beacon so that I can do something with it. If there was an easy way to just get notified of a beacon once with some id and its telemetry data, even better. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ends up I was on the right track at least per other examples I've found. On range notification I check for beacons.size() and when its > 0, I work with the details and then tell it to stopRangeNotifications.

The problem was background notifications and the time between scans was too high to debug as background helper sets up a 5min scan by default.

This will need some tuning, but seems to serve my purposes.